# $G$ is a compact group. Are 'periodic' functions dense in $C(G)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, group-theory

Assume $G$ is a group, $f$ is a continous real number valued function on $G$. The $G$-action on $f$ is given by $(gf)(a)=f(g^{-1}a)$.

Say $f$ is periodic, when $Gf$ is contained in some finite dimensional (real) linear space.

For example, let $G=\mathbb T$, the circle group, then functions like $\sin(n\theta)$ and $\cos(n\theta)$ are periodic, since $(\zeta\sin)(n\theta)=\sin(n(\theta-\zeta))=\sin(n\theta)\cos(n\zeta)-\cos(n\theta)\sin(n\zeta)$, which is always contained in the linear space generated by $\sin(n\theta)$ and $\cos(n\theta)$.

Therefore, by Fourier series, periodic functions in $C(\mathbb T)$ are dense.

The question is, assume $G$ is compact, is the set of periodic functions always dense in $C(G)$ in general?

Comment: This should follow from the Peter-Weyl theorem; I'm not posting that as answer since the Peter-Weyl theorem assumes complex-valued functions and is about $L^2(G)$ rather than $C(G)$; I think both these obstructions are easily overcome, though.

Comment: Yes,indeed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem

Comment: @hunter But $C(G)\subset L^2(G)$, no?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn yes it is; I guess you also have to worry about the topologies but it's fine because uniform convergence implies $L^2$ convergence.